# Vlookup for textbox in the whole workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to solve this problem:
I'm having a table in Sheet1, in column A there'll be names of several text boxes in the workbook, in column B there'll be values for the corresponding text boxes.
The string in Column B exceeded 256 characters (probably >1000 characters) so I can't link the text boxes to the corresponding cells by formula.
In short, I want a vlookup for text boxes in the whole workbook (with multiple sheets).
Is this possible? Any help would be appreciated :D
Thanks in advanced.[sampledownload](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1rt_arl-NJqWHNOem9qTlU5dGs/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: add an example of your data

Comment: Hi, this is a sample file  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1rt_arl-NJqWHNOem9qTlU5dGs/view?usp=sharing